# Angular state redirection for blank model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Ok, I know the title is a little ambiguous, but I couldn't think of a descriptive title. I will try to explain my issue here.

I have some states set up like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('designer', {
    url: '/:sport/designer',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/index.tpl.html',
    controller: 'DesignerController',
    controllerAs: 'controller'
}).state('designer.team', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/team.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.kit', {
    url: '/kit',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/kit.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.design', {
    url: '/design',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/design.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.refine', {
    url: '/refine',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/refine.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.order', {
    url: '/order',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/order.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.save', {
    url: '/save',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/save.tpl.html',
    data: {
        requireLogin: true
    }
});
```

The idea is simple, there are a few steps that allow a user to customise a kit. When they get to the last step (save) they have to login / register in order to save (for obvious reasons).
So I build my controller like this:

```
.controller('DesignerController', ['$stateParams', 'Api', 'Array', 'TemplateService', function ($stateParams, api, array, service) {
    var self = this,
        slug = $stateParams.sport;    

    // Empty model to handle the first time loading
    self.kit = {
        loading: false,
        data: {
            name: '',

            selectedGarments: [],
            selectedDesign: 'Angelus',
            total: '00.00',

            team: {
                name: '',
                clubName: '',
                sport: '',

                selectedColours: []
            }
        }
    };

    self.sport = api.get('/categories', { slug: slug }); // Get our sport
    self.colours = ['000000', 'FFFFFF', '00adef', 'ed008c', 'fef200', '2e3192', '00a652', 'ed1b24', 'c7c8ca', 'f14e23', '6c9d30', 'c0d731', 'f5a3c7', '816ab0', '082140', '1e4f2f', '5bcaf5', 'f04e3f', 'f68b1f', 'cdbe01', 'ee4d9b', '007193', '5f1e08', '841c3d']; // Get current colours
    self.designs = ['Angelus', 'Claudius', 'Equitius', 'Fang', 'Valerius']; // Get current designs
    self.garments = { loading: true }; // Empty object to be populated by service

    // After we get our sport, get our garments
    self.sport.promise.then(function () {

        // Get the category id
        var categoryId = self.sport.data[0].id;

        // Get all the garments that belong to that category
        self.garments = api.get('products', { categoryId: categoryId });
    });

    // Set our colours
    self.setColour = function (colour) {
        var colours = self.kit.data.team.selectedColours;

        array.modify(colours, colour);
    };

    // Set our design
    self.setDesign = function (design) {
        self.kit.data.selectedDesign = design;
    };

    // Set our garments
    self.setGarment = function (garment) {
        var garments = self.kit.data.selectedGarments;

        array.modify(garments, garment);
    };
}]);
```

Now, as you can see the **self.kit** object is pretty much blank to start.
Each **state** handles different parts of the view model.

- Team - handles all the team stuff
- Kit - handles the garment selection
- Design - handles the selected design
- Order - doesn't modify the view model, but it uses all the previous **state** data to display information
- Save - is when the "kit" is saved

So, my question is is there anyway to prevent loading the next state if the previous state values have not been completed? And also, can you redirect to a state depending on what values have been completed on load (I plan on holding the **kit** in sessionStorage)?

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I would just use flags that are stored in a progress object, and do a check against it whenever they try to progress. progress.part1 = true/false, progress.part2 = true/false

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$stateChangeStart` to prevent the event change, but also you will need some service like some "`DesignerWizardManager`" or similar, and you can save the state using $window.localStorage or similar.

```
angular.module('pcmacClientApp', [])
  .run(function($rootScope, DesignerStepManager) { 
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
      function(event, next, nextParams, prev, prevParams) {

        var canNavigateToStep = DesignerStepManager.canNavigateThrougth(next);

        if(!canNavigateToStep) {
          event.preventDefault();
       } else if(DesignerStepManager.hasProgress() {
           $rootScope.$state.go(DesignerStepManager.getCurrentStateName());
           //also you could add stateParams
       }
});
```